# SSH ProxyCommand with AWS Session Manager - no shell started

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, ssh, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to setup proxy that connects via AWS Session Manager with ssh command (to be used by ansible). As of right now, I'm able to connect to my vm with AWS CLI command like so

```
aws ssm start-session --target i-XXXXXXXXX
```

With that in mind, I tried to setup ProxyCommand in my ssh config, the same that was recommended by AWS

```
host i-* mi-*
    ProxyCommand sh -c "aws ssm start-session --target %h --document-name AWS-StartSSHSession --parameters 'portNumber=%p' --region eu-west-2"
```

Now it gets weird, it appears as connection is opened but it just hangs there, not redirecting input to vm, not printing prompt.

```
$ ssh i-XXXXXXXXXXXX  -vvvvvvvvv
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/foo/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/foo/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for i-*
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec sh -c "aws ssm start-session --target i-XXXXXXXXXXXX --document-name AWS-StartSSHSession --parameters 'portNumber=22' --region eu-west-2"
debug1: permanently_drop_suid: 1000
debug1: identity file /home/foo/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/foo/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/foo/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/foo/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/foo/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/foo/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/foo/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/foo/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: ssh_exchange_identification: 

debug1: ssh_exchange_identification: Starting session with SessionId: botocore-session-1563202442-0d72a7be446ee1035

debug1: ssh_exchange_identification: \033[?1034hsh-4.2$ 
\033[Ksh-4.2$ SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3


debug1: ssh_exchange_identification: sh: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1: command not found


debug1: ssh_exchange_identification: sh-4.2$
```

Any ideas? I've tried the same config on linux and windows, updated OpenSSH to 8.x, nothing is working.

Answer (score 4):

## SSM plugin and agent version

- Ensure that version **1.1.23.0** or later of the Session Manager plugin is installed. See [Manually Install SSM Agent on Amazon EC2 Linux Instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager-working-with-install-plugin.html#install-plugin-linux)
- Ensure that SSM Agent version **2.3.672.0** or later is installed on the instance. See [Manually Install SSM Agent on Amazon EC2 Linux Instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/sysman-manual-agent-install.html)

### Related

- [Getting SSH tunnels with AWS SSM Running](https://spock.rocks/tech/2019/07/13/aws-ssm-ssh-tunnels.html)

Comment: For anyone else finding this, the version number of the Linux agent was a useful clue for Ubuntu-based servers because the SSM plugin maintainers still have not shipped the version with support for SSH in the stable snap channel, which means you need to follow the instructions in https://github.com/aws/amazon-ssm-agent/issues/196 to `snap switch --channel=candidate amazon-ssm-agent` before a refresh will install a version compatible with SSH.